# Noninformative prior for variance

Tags: self-study, jeffreys-prior

In Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine learning, he states that if you want a noninformative prior for scale,$$\int_A^Bp(\sigma)d\sigma = \int_{A/c}^{B/c}p(\sigma)d\sigma = \int_A^Bp\left(\frac{1}{c}\sigma\right)\frac{1}{c}d\sigma$$

This means that the probability that $\sigma$ is between $A$ and $B$ needs to be the same as if you scaled the standard deviation by a scaling factor $c$ (first quality). This is accomplished by scaling down the density at each of those values of $\frac{1}{c}\sigma$ by a factor of $c$ (second equality). Intuitively, this makes sense to me.

Then, he equates the integrands to get $$p(\sigma) = p\left(\frac{1}{c}\sigma\right)\frac{1}{c}$$ and concludes that $$p(\sigma) \propto \frac{1}{\sigma}$$

My questions are:

1. How can you equate the integrands just because the integrals are equal?
2. How do you go from that equality to the statement of proportionality?

Answer (score 0):

1. The fundamental theorem of calculus says that the integrand is the derivative of the integral, and so the derivative of the cdf defines the density (up to a set of measure zero).
2. The simplest answer is that if two quantities functions are equal, then they are also proportional, but that masks a complication; that is, the non-informative prior is improper.  That is, it integrates to infinity, and so, since norming to have an integral of 1 is out of the question, there's no reason not to use any multiple of the invers of the standard deviation.